# EMC, resistors and trimpots

Tags: resistors, emc, esd

I trying to get EMC certification and stumbled upon problem.

[image]

In the above circuit, they will apply ESD to the exposed part of the trim pot, and it permanently changes the value of the trim pot and the resistors R1, and R2. Are there such resistors and Trim pots that are specially designed to withstand ESD?

Trim-pot seems to be affected also by conductive noise injection from the power supply line which is isolated and fed via voltage regulator. Is there specific parameter I have too look for when searching for resistors and trim-pots?

Answer (score 1):

An ESD test to the adjust screw of a trim pot would not normally change the mechanically adjusted value or value of other fixed resistors.  If your equipment malfunctions when the ESD test is administered then the fault may lie else where, such as the ESD charge getting into other circuitry, or the charge not dissipating to an earth ground.

A solution might be to find a similar trim pot that has a plastic (rather then a metal) adjustment screw.  Yet another possibility would be to put the trim pot further into the assembly and have a plastic extension piece to the screw.  If the ESD test shows an error that simulates a fast trim pot change then you might be able to adjust your software to temporarily disregard any fast changes.

Comment: An extreme option might be to put a thin spring loaded wire up against the metal trim screw edge, with the wire connected to a ground. This should help redirect the ESD charge away from the internal circuitry.

Comment: I thought that trim pot was supposed to be only mechanical part. However, I tested trimpot alone and it shows substantially different resistance across terminal after I apply ESD to it.

Comment: I think the change in resistance is due to a spark flying inside the trimmer, which burns some of the carbon.

Comment: @PkP I looked at the data sheet for the trimpot and it is made of material called "Cermet" which is ceramic and metal composite. Like You said, it might be that the ESD have changed the device's characteristics

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your trimpot is exposed? Maybe you could bury it inside the casing and bring out a twist knob of some proper material for adjustment?

Comment: The mechanical constraints forbid me from doing that.

Comment: Also, trim-pot seems to be affected by conductive noise on the power line

Comment: Hmm. Is the trimpot adjustment knob/ring made of metal? How about some coat of some material? No, I guess not... Hmm... not even a *small* knob? Just something over the metal?

Comment: Yes, the knob is made of metal. I really wish the engineer who designed this product have used something else...

Comment: Well, they all have the metal contact. But some are encased in plastic.